# Please check my proof for $x^2+|x-2|>1$

Tags: calculus, inequality, solution-verification

Let $f(x)=x^2+|x-2|-1$.

If $x <2,$ then
$f(x)=x^2-x+1 \implies f'(x)=2x-1 \implies f_{min}=f(1/2)=\frac{3}{4} >1.$

If $x>2$, then $f(x)=x^2+x-3 \implies f'(x)=2x+1>0$. So the function is increasing for $x>2$

The function $f(x)$ has just one min, so $f(x)>f(1/3)=3/4  >0$, hence for all real values $x^2+|x-2| >1.$.

Is my proof correct. What can be other methods to prove this?

Comment: Certainly you mean $f(1/2) = 3/4 > 0$, both instances.

Comment: No, it's very wrong. First, you simply can't apply this method in the first place, since $f$ is not differentiable. (If you want to use calculus you need to include the points where the function is not differentiable as critical points to check). Also $f(1/2)\ne3/4$, and by the way $3/4<1$.

Comment: Why a negative vote for a correct  question and a query?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $|x-2|$ is $\pm1$, depending on the sign of $x-2$. Hence the extrema can be located at

$$2x=\pm1.$$ The root $x=-\dfrac12<2$ must be rejected, and the global minimum is

$$\frac1{2^2}+\left|\frac12-2\right|>1.$$

---

To address David's objections, notice that the function is differentiable for all $x\ne 2$, and continuous at $f(2)>1$, so the computation of the global minimum by differentiation makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

A standard way to prove such an inequality without derivatives would be to complete the square.

For $x \ge 2$ the case is simpler:

$$x^2 + |x-2| \ge 4 + 0 > 1$$

For $x < 2$ we have $|x - 2| = 2-x$. Hence:

$$\begin{align}x^2 + |x-2| &= x^2-x+2 \\&= x^2-x+\frac14 + \frac74 \\&= \left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\frac 74 \\&\ge \frac74>1\end{align}$$

using the fact that squares are nonnegative.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative we have that

$$x^2+|x-2|>1\iff x^2-1>-|x-2|$$

which is trivially true for $x<-1$ and $x>1$ then for $|x|\le1$ we obtain

$$x^2-x+1>0$$

which is true since $\Delta<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Ehen $x>2$ the inequation is $$x*2+x-3 >0\implies x \in (-\infty, \frac{-1-\sqrt{13}}{2}) \cup (\frac{\sqrt{13}-1}{2}, \infty)$$
So the solution is $x \in (2, \infty).$
When $x \le 2$, the inequation becomes $x^2-x+1>0$ which is true as $B^2< 4AC$. Then the solutions are $(-\infty, 2]$.

Finally, the solutions of this inequation are all real numbers, hence proved.